# Tips factoring formula to form of $\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{g(x)}+\frac{1}{h(x)}+...?$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

$$\frac{1}{x^4(x^2+1)}=\frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}$$

I'm having trouble transforming this kind of equation. The goal is to transform the orignal formula to mutiple formulas and keep the numerators = 1.

is there a systematic method to do it?

Comment: [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)

Comment: @user170231 I know this method, but it can't ensure every numerator = 1.

Comment: The first example in the link demonstrates that what you seek cannot be done in general, at least for polynomial $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ etc.